# Porque me queda una lista dentro de la otra?

Tags: python

construi una funcion que recibe un numero y puede existir un parámetro opcional de entrada lista.  La función debe retornar una lista con los cuadrados de 0 hasta el numero de entrada

Ejemplos

def cuad(num, lista=...). f(2) -> [0, 1, 4], f(5) -> [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25], f(2, [16, 25]) -> [16, 25, 0, 1, 4], f(3, [100, -1, 0]) -> [100, -1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 9].

```
def f(number, *args):
    a = list(args)
    for i in range (0, number+1):
        a.insert(len(a), i ** 2)
    return a
```

sin embargo para el ejemplo f(2, [16,25]) me retorna [[16,25], 0, 1, 4]. debiendo ser [16, 25, 0, 1, 4].  Agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando pones un asterisco delante de un parámetro al definir una función (como en tu caso `*args`) estás pidiendo a python que *todos* los parámetros que la función reciba a partir de ese punto los junte en una lista, y que te deje esa lista en `args`. Si no le pasas nada en ese punto, la lista `args` que recibirá la función estará vacía.

Así, si llamas a tu función con `f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` entonces los parámetros que va a recibir la función son:

- `number` el valor 1
- `args` la lista `[2, 3, 4, 5]`

Fíjate que no has pasado una lista a la función, sino una serie de parámetros, pero asterisco ha hecho que la función los vea como una lista.

Si la llamas con `f(1)`, en `args` recibirías `[]`.

Por tanto este mecanismo no es para recibir un parámetro opcional, sino cualquier número de parámetros extra después del primero `number`.

Ahora bien, si invocas la función con `f(1, [2, 3, 4, 5])`, solo estás pasando un parámetro adicional después de `number` (que es de tipo lista) y entonces lo que verá la función será:

- `number` el valor 1
- `args` la lista `[[2,3,4,5]]`

Fijate que en este caso la lista recibida en `args` tiene un solo valor (porque la función sólo ha recibido un parámetro después del 1), pero ese valor es una lista (que es el valor del parámetro que has pasado después del 1).

Si tú quieres que la función se adapte a ambos casos, debe mirar de qué tipo son los elementos de `args`. Si `args[0]` es una lista, tendrá que "desempaquetar" sus elementos (puede usar el operador `*` para ello, que cuando aparece en una expresión hace lo contrario que cuando aparece en la declaración de un parámetro).

Es decir, tu función podría ser así:

```
def f(number, *args):
  if args and isinstance(args[0], list):
     a = list(*args[0])
  else:
     a = list(args)  # En rigor se podría hacer simplemente a=args
  for i in range (0, number+1):
        a.append(i ** 2)
  return a
```

Por cierto que he aprovechado para cambiar el `.insert()` que tú usabas por un `.append()`, que añade automáticamente al final de la lista.

**Nota**: La función anterior servirá para el caso particular por el que preguntas, pero no funcionará correctamente si le pasas a `f` más parámetros además de la lista (o si la lista no es el primer parámetro). Es decir, no admite llamadas como `f(1, [2, 3], 4)` o `f(1, 2, [3,4])`. Te dejo como ejercicio mejorarla para que admita también esto. Pista: puedes iterar por los elementos de `args` y ver para cada uno si es de tipo lista o no, e ir agregándolo adecuadamente a la lista `a`.

### Edición

Pero leyendo mejor tu enunciado, no parece que haya que complicarse tanto. No te pide en ningún momento que admitas la sintaxis `f(1,2,3,4)`, sino solo la sintaxis con lista, si bien ésta puede ser *opcional*.

Para esto no debes usar la sintaxis `*`, sino asignarle un valor por defecto a ese parámetro. Lo típico suele ser asignarle `None` por defecto, y después dentro de la función verificar si el valor es `None` (lo que significa que no se le ha pasado parámetro a la función) o distinto de `None` (lo que significa que se le ha pasado un parámetro, en este caso una lista). Así que esta implementación sería:

```py
def f(number, lista=None):
  if lista is None:
     a = [] 
  else:
     a = lista.copy()     # Copia para evitar modificar la original
  for i in range (0, number+1):
        a.append(i ** 2)
  return a
```